# most cruel vs cruelest

Tags: grammar

Why do people say "the most cruel persons..." instead of cruelest? Isn't the declination of cruel => cruel, crueler, the cruelest or is it cruel, more cruel, most cruel?

i mean which is the correct?

Comment: Google's [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most+cruel%2Ccruelest%2Ccruellest&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) bears out what you suppose in the year 1800, but today they are about the same, and if you merged 'cruelest' with 'cruellest' they would probably outrank 'most cruel'. But does there need to be a  reason why language is used the way it is? It isn't a rational thing.

Comment: 'Cruel' is generally regarded as disyllabic, and there is often a choice when forming the comparative / superlative of such words. See for instance [Conundrum: cleverer or more clever? simpler or more simple? etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc). 'Crueller' and 'cruellest' tend to sound weak when spoken, not optimal for words with such a strong meaning. But as Weather Vane says, the best way is to check normal usage patterns. The 'rules' are not absolute; 'more fun' but sometimes 'curiouser'.

Comment: 'Most' isn't necessarily a superlative (more cruel than anyone else) but can be used for emphasis. As Edwin says, "You are most cruel" has a lot more punch than "You are cruelest."

Comment: Contrary to what is said above, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cruel) says "cruel" can be pronounced with one or two syllables, which makes any rule tricky to apply.

Comment: Curiouser is from Lewis Caroll. *You are most cruel*. (\is like in Dickens: You are most kind, Sir.) is an old-fashioned way of saying: You are very cruel. It is not the same as: You are the crulest person I know. Which of course, can be said as: the most cruel person I know.

Comment: What people? "the most cruel persons" returns "About 1 search result" (from study.com): "Adolf Hitler was known for being one of **the most cruel persons** in history." Not fluent people, it seems.

Comment: There are some monosyllabic adjectives which normally take more/most, e.g. *fun*. So you have to learn the rule and the exceptions.

Comment: @StuartF  I provided the rule in my answer but not every irregular adjective. That misses the point for two syllable adjectives.

Answer (score 2):

Question: Why do people say "the most cruel persons..." instead of cruelest?

Native speakers might say either one. The general rule is that two syllable adjectives form the superlative by adding est to the last one: funny, funniest; poor, poorest; silly, silliest. Those are just examples and do not include irregular adjective like: good, better, best.

However, there is no rule against using the form: the most [adjective]

**Two-syllable adjectives** (**Some can use either the suffixes or the more-most technique**.)
clever, cleverer, cleverest or clever, more clever, most clever **cruel,** **crueler, cruelest or cruel, more cruel, most cruel**

[adjectives+ comparative and superlative](https://www.grammar.com/states-of-adjectives-er-or-more-est-or-most/)